# How to read environment in Vue.js app on Rails via webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vue.js, webpacker

I would like to do something similar like Rails.env.test? but withing Vue.js app which is setup via Rails & Webpacker.

How to do it?

Comment: Marked as a duplicate since Webpacker runs on Node.js. See https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html

Comment: process.env.NODE_ENV worked.